# Auto arrange tables in xcdatamodel

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, xcdatamodel

I was arranging my tables in the `xcdatamodel` using my trackpad, and suddently while I was holding a table it moved it too far away from the other tables, how can I move it back down, it's too far to drag it, is there some sort of auto-arange?[image]

Answer (score 0):

None that I know. But using the arrow keys works better than the mouse for finer movements.